# BASH: Read all files in a directory recursively, includinging symbolic links

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, sh

I got this tidy script from someone:

```
find  ../Classes -name \*.cpp -print
```

which simply loops a directory, and prints all files recursively. However, it doesn't follow symlinks. All I can find online is:

```
find ../Classes -name \*.cpp -type l -print
```

But, since the directory is the symlink, not the files, it outputs nothing.
How can I solve that?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the recursive descent to follow a link to a different directory tree?

Comment: @WilliamPursell what Cfreak answered is what I am after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell `find` to follow symlinks with `-L`

```
find  -L ../Classes -name \*.cpp -print
```