# Force find to look through all subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, find, rhel

I searched for log files on a server using `find`, like this:

```
find . -name "*log*"
```

This didn't return anything useful, so I looked through some configuration files and discovered some log files in a subdirectory called `build/private`.

If I pass that directory name directly to `find`, it will discover those log files:

```
find ./build/private -name "*log*"
```

So it looks like `find` is ignoring some subdirectories by default. Therefore, I'm not sure what other log files I'm missing.

I looked through `find`'s manual page but I didn't see any options that would force it to go through all subdirectories and look at all files.

Is there such an option?

Why does it not look through all subdirectories?

Comment: Have you checked `build` and `private` permissions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BASH: Read all files in a directory recursively, includinging symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693828/bash-read-all-files-in-a-directory-recursively-includinging-symbolic-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` works with subdirectories just fine. Your name pattern does not match any files.

You might be better off using `grep` for the pattern matching, for example, this will find all files with '.log' extention on the end, but not 'logchopper.py':

```
find . | grep '\.log$'
```

Comment: This command does not work in finding the log files either, regardless of whether I use the `$` or not.

Comment: can you do `find . | grep build | grep private` and see the result ?

Comment: Yes, nothing is shown. I actually noticed that `build` is a symlink.

Comment: @octavian ok, let's make it simpler: `ls | grep build` ? and `find . | grep build` ?

Comment: So it looks like `find` doesn't go on symlinks. Do you know if there is an option to make it recurse symlinks as well?

Comment: @octavian have you tried `-L` ? =)